# Ajax errors on upload fields

Tags: 7, ajax, media

I have an image field that allows a single image to be uploaded. The selection works, but if I click upload, I get an AJAX error. If I just submit without uploading first, the image is uploaded properly. If I go in to edit that image field and click remove, I again get an ajax error.

```
An error occurred while attempting to process /file/ajax/field_front_image/und/0/form-XprUtXJvTcMRlmsz3CmBs6uDFpuJcev4SO_I_PvsM-E: Array.prototype.reverse called on null or undefined
```

I get this error locally and on the production server. It happens for all image fields and it's the same error when clicking upload or remove.

How can I fix the ajax on these form fields?

Comment: What kind of Image modules do you have installed?

Comment: just the core image module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check your theme's jQuery and Drupal jQuery conflicts. Check 'View source' and check the jQuery version the page using.

I had similar issue when used latest jQuery in my theme.

Comment: So I have some mootools code being loaded as well. It's not the entirety of mootools, but I'm beginning to suspect that it may be conflicting somehow. I'm going to disable some javascript and see what I come up with.

Comment: is any custom code involved or are you working solely with core and drupal modules/themes?  is it possible that someone forgot to wrap custom jquery (http://drupal.org/node/772500)?

Comment: solved the problem on by installing jQuery Update module and setting the JQuery version to 1.8

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem in 2 month ago. this problem issues form  server and not depended to drupal core.we try to solve this problem, and test any ideas(clean drupal cache,  recreate fields, change permission of file directories )but all of them not work.
Just I can suggest you  put you contentrate in server and cache layer of server( nginx cache, varnish cache if you have )

maybe be useful using [clearstatecache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) 
and commands like this.

**Certaintly problem is in server not in drupal**